# Concatenate two column data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have below table.

[image]

Now In the above table ENO,ENAME,Edept are existing column. Now I want to calculate the FINAL COLUMN as above.

Please help me with the query to get the FINAL column result.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you saying that `eno`, `ename`, and `edept` are all `varchar2` columns that contain a pipe-separated set of values??  And that you want to produce a pipe and comma-separated result??  You realize that violates every last rule of proper database design, right?

Comment: Yes all are varchar. I dont have any other option as the downstream system requires this kind of data.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily matter what a downstream server needs if you can extract it and send it in the format that expects. That shouldn't affect how you store the data yourself. Is this table populated from other tables that are organised relationally? If so how is it populated - is it actually a view that uses `listagg()`, say?

Comment: Are the number of fields in each column (no of pipes) fixed or variable? I don't have a database at hand to test but my first thought would be that if the number of pipe is fixed and small then something like:

Comment: number of fields are variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mixture of SUBSTR and INSTR functions like so -

see demo at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad1d4/40/0

```
select substr(eno,1,instr(eno,'|',1,1)-1)
       ||','||
       substr(ename,1,instr(ename,'|',1,1)-1)
       ||','||
       substr(edept,1,instr(edept,'|',1,1)-1)
       ||'|'||
       substr(eno,instr(eno,'|',1,1)+1,instr(eno,'|',1,2)-3)
       ||','||
       substr(ename,instr(ename,'|',1,1)+1,instr(ename,'|',1,2)-3)
       ||','||
       substr(edept,instr(edept,'|',1,1)+1,instr(edept,'|',1,2)-3)
       ||
       substr(eno,instr(eno,'|',1,2)+1,length(eno)-instr(eno,'|',1,2)+1)
       ||','||
       substr(ename,instr(ename,'|',1,2)+1,length(ename)-instr(ename,'|',1,2)+1)
       ||','||
       substr(edept,instr(edept,'|',1,2)+1,length(edept)-instr(edept,'|',1,2)+1)
as final_column
from tbl
```

Comment: Only if there are exactly three values in each concatenated column though ([it breaks with 4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7889/1)). It's possible to make this more generic but it would be much better to fix the data model.

Answer (score 0):

If you have regular need. And if that table has not many others query.

You could add the column FINAL in the table and add a trigger on it 
like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER schema.TBI_name
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON schema.TBLE_name 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
        :NEW.FINAL := 1||','||
                   REPLACE(:NEW.eno,'|',',')
                   ||'|'||2||','||
                   REPLACE(:NEW.ename,'|',',')
                   ||'|'||3||','||
                   REPLACE(:NEW.edept,'|',',');
END TBI_name;
```